# HTTP 500 / NullPointerException at the end of the SonarQube build downloading retrieving issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

In the Jenkins build, here's the stack we have:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project gwt-parent: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent]: Fail to download [http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent]. Response code: 500 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project gwt-parent: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent]
   [snip]
   ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:139)
    at org.sonar.batch.repository.DefaultServerIssuesLoader.load(DefaultServerIssuesLoader.java:49)
  [snip]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent]. Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:305)
  [snip]
```

And on the Server

```
2015.08.31 12:56:55 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://forge.mipih.net/sonar/batch/issues?key=fr.pgih.socle%3Agwt-parent
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonar.batch.protocol.input.BatchInput$ServerIssue$Builder.setModuleKey(BatchInput.java:1451) ~[sonar-batch-protocol-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.batch.IssuesAction.handleIssue(IssuesAction.java:96) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.batch.IssuesAction.handle(IssuesAction.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor170.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        [snip]
```

But indeed, this URL is accessible from my browser. Here's what it serves:

```
{"errors":[{"msg":""}]}
```

Do you have any idea where it might come from?

Just in case, FYI, SonarQube 5.1.1 is running through the official sonarqube & mysql images.

I've crawled the changelog from 5.1.2, and I didn't find an obviously related issue. Is this a known issue?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are facing the same issue reported [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6012?focusedCommentId=43326&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-43326), at least it's the exact same stacktrace, which is fixed since 5.1.

Only case left where this error could occur is if the Jenkins job you are running is trying to analyse a deleted module.
Since analyzing a module is a bit odd, you might be analyzing a module which used to be a project.
Fix would then be to update your Jenkins job to analyse the new project.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure I get the point. As said above, I'm already running 5.1.1 and still having this issue. Hence I suppose this is the remainder of your answer that may be relevant here? Thanks

Comment: Baptiste, can you check that fr.pgih.socle:gwt-parent is a project and not a module ? Can you check you can see it in a SonarQube dashboard ? Thanks.